# Telegram bot logs Error code 409 even though there is single instance running

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, render.com

I have deployed my Telegram bot on Heroku written in Python (PyTelegramBotAPI) before and it was working without any issue. Today I tried to migrate it to Render.com. I stopped my Dyno and deployed it on Render and it logs below error. I tried deleting the Dyno completely and render still logs the same error. Finally I tried revoking the bot key but the issue is still the same. I'm certain I don't run any extra instance of the bot. The weird part is the bot still responds for a little time after all the instances are stopped or deleted. Finally I deployed it again on Heroku and it's working just fine. How can I fix that?

[Botcode](https://github.com/pasindujr/HnditHelperBot)

Error:

```
(__init__.py:688 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running into the same issue here. Looks like an incarnation of Heroku's "[preboot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot)" feature, more details here: https://community.render.com/t/having-2-instances-after-deploy/3640.

TL;DR: It's impossible to disable it on render.com :-/

Comment: So the only option here is to go back to Heroku right?

Comment: I believe it should be possible to implement via distributed locking (https://redis.io/topics/distlock) but it's your call about whether it's worth the effort.

Comment: I just ignore the error, and It goes away after 10 seconds. Though it is not an optimized solution, I want to keep all of my apps in 1 place.

Comment: I'd argue that ignoring a problem is not a solution...